# How to make the tkinter window responsive with the widgets placed using pack() method in Tkinter Python?

Tags: python, oop, tkinter

#### **I want my widgets of my gui to get managed when the size of the GUI Window gets increase or decrease according to the monitor size.**

With my current code this window looks like this in my monitor ---
[Look of the gui when open in my pc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9Gh3.png)

And when the same GUI program is open in another monitor screen of same size, the some part of the window gets cut off --
[Look of the gui window in another pc monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3S5H.png)

**But I want my GUI Window to adjust all its widgets with the monitor screen.**

Please help me with this and please suggest me what should I add to my code to make it responsive !!

**Note - I have used pack() method to place the Label Frames**

My some line of code ---

```
class Application:
def __init__(self, root):
    self.root = root
    self.root.title("Auto-Garage Management Application")
    self.screen_width = self.root.winfo_screenwidth()
    self.screen_height = self.root.winfo_screenheight()
    self.root.geometry("%dx%d+-10+0" % (self.screen_width, self.screen_height))

    bg_color1 = "#ff704d"
    bg_color2 = "powder blue"

    # =============== Fonts
    frame_label_font = Font(family="Poppins", size=20, weight="bold")
    entry_label_font1 = Font(family="Roboto", size=17, weight="bold")
    entry_label_font2 = Font(family="Roboto", size=15, weight="bold")
    entry_font = Font(family="Noto Sans", size=15, weight="bold")
    btn_font = Font(family="Noto Sans", size=15, weight="bold")

    # ================ Variables 
    # Customer Details
    self.customer_name = StringVar()
    self.customer_phone = StringVar()
    self.customer_telno = StringVar()
    self.customer_address_1 = StringVar()
    self.customer_address_2 = StringVar()
    self.customer_address_3 = StringVar()
    
    # ========== Customer Details
    customer_details_frame = LabelFrame(self.root, text="Customer Details", bg=bg_color1, fg="black",
                                        font=frame_label_font, bd=6, relief=GROOVE)
    customer_details_frame.pack(fill=BOTH)

    # Customer Name
    customer_name = Label(customer_details_frame, text="Customer Name", bg=bg_color1, fg="yellow", font=entry_label_font1)
    customer_name.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20, pady=5)

    customer_name_txt = Entry(customer_details_frame, textvariable=self.customer_name, width=22, font=entry_font, bd=5, relief=SUNKEN)
    customer_name_txt.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10)

    # Customer Phone Number
    customer_phone = Label(customer_details_frame, text="Customer Phone", bg=bg_color1, fg="yellow", font=entry_label_font1)
    customer_phone.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=20, pady=5)

    customer_phone_txt = Entry(customer_details_frame, textvariable=self.customer_phone, width=22, font=entry_font, bd=5, relief=SUNKEN)
    customer_phone_txt.grid(row=0, column=3, padx=10)

    customer_phone2 = Label(customer_details_frame, text="Customer Tel No.", bg=bg_color1, fg="yellow", font=entry_label_font1)
    customer_phone2.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=10)

    customer_phone2_txt = Entry(customer_details_frame, textvariable=self.customer_telno, width=22, font=entry_font, bd=5, relief=SUNKEN)
    customer_phone2_txt.grid(row=1, column=3, padx=10)

    # Customer Address
    customer_address = Label(customer_details_frame, text="Customer Address", bg=bg_color1, fg="yellow", font=entry_label_font1)
    customer_address.grid(row=0, column=4, padx=20, pady=5)

    customer_address_txt1 = Entry(customer_details_frame, textvariable=self.customer_address_1, width=22, font=entry_font, bd=5, relief=SUNKEN)
    customer_address_txt1.grid(row=0, column=5, padx=10)

    customer_address_txt2 = Entry(customer_details_frame, textvariable=self.customer_address_2, width=22, font=entry_font, bd=5, relief=SUNKEN)
    customer_address_txt2.grid(row=1, column=5, padx=10)

    customer_address_txt3 = Entry(customer_details_frame, textvariable=self.customer_address_3, width=22, font=entry_font, bd=5, relief=SUNKEN)
    customer_address_txt3.grid(row=2, column=5, padx=10, pady=5)

    app = Tk()
    software = Application(app)
    app.mainloop()
```

#### Thanks For Any Help !!!

Comment: Showing us some code will help.

Comment: I don't think it is easy to create responsive layout using tkinter.

Comment: What else I can use to make responsive gui in python instead of tkinter ??

Comment: @acw1668: that depends on how you define "responsive". It's quite easy to make a UI that fits multiple sizes of windows. However, to have the font automatically scale up or down takes a bit more work. It can be done though.

Comment: It looks like your problem is mostly due to using a hard-coded font that's too big for the smaller monitor. The simple answer seems to be "use a smaller font". Without seeing a minimal example that we can use to see how you're creating the GUI, it's going to be hard for us to give you better advice.

Comment: @BryanOakley Responsive is not just changing font size, it needs to re-arrange widgets to fit the available space as well.  For example, change from portrait to landscape mode.

Comment: @acw1668: yes, that's the full definition of "responsive". I'm guessing what the OP want's isn't so much fully responsive but rather just shrink or grow to fit the window with the same layout.

Comment: But I don't want to be responsive in just landscape and portrait mode. The widgets should shrink and fit in the window size in any monitor size and it should not show the half widget as you can see in second image, that's what I want. If you want code then commet.

Answer (score 0):

`pack` and `grid` both have options that help you define where extra space goes, and how widgets grow, shrink, and align in the space that is given. Creating a layout that is somewhat responsive simply requires careful use of those options.

It appears you're also using a hard-coded font size. It's possible to get the size of the window, and then choose a font size that is appropriate for the window size.

### Laying out the widgets.

While it would take far too much code to simulate the entire UI, here's how I would create the top panel. Notice how weight is given to the columns with entry widgets so that they grow if there is any extra space. I also use the `sticky` option to make sure they fill the space given to them.

```
class CustomerDetails(tk.LabelFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.name = tk.Entry(self)
        self.phone = tk.Entry(self)
        self.telno = tk.Entry(self)
        self.addr1 = tk.Entry(self)
        self.addr2 = tk.Entry(self)
        self.addr3 = tk.Entry(self)

        name_label = tk.Label(self, text="Customer Name")
        phone_label = tk.Label(self, text="Customer Phone")
        telno_label = tk.Label(self, text="Customer Tel No.")
        addr_label = tk.Label(self, text="Customer Address")

        self.grid_columnconfigure((1,3,5), weight=1)

        name_label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="e")
        phone_label.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky="e")
        telno_label.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky="e")
        addr_label.grid(row=0, column=4, sticky="e")

        self.name.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="ew")
        self.phone.grid(row=0, column=3, sticky="ew")
        self.telno.grid(row=1, column=3, sticky="ew")
        self.addr1.grid(row=0, column=5, sticky="ew")
        self.addr2.grid(row=1, column=5, sticky="ew")
        self.addr3.grid(row=2, column=5, sticky="ew")
```

You can then add this widget to the root window using `pack` like in the following example. Notice how it defines both the `fill` and `expand` options to control how it behaves when it doesn't exactly fit the window.

```
root = tk.Tk()
details = CustomerDetails(root, text="Customer Details")
details.pack(side="top", fill="x", expand=False)
```

If you run this code you'll notice that the widgets all fit in both a very narrow and very wide window. Of course, if the window is too small then the entry widgets become unusuable.

### Dynamically changing font sizes.

By default, labels will use a font named `TkDefaultFont` and entry and text widgets use `TkTextFont`. If you rely on these defaults, you can change the fonts and all of the widgets will change accordingly. You can then either get the size of the display and pick the correct size before the UI is created, or you can set it up so that as the window is resized, the fonts change automatically.

To get a reference to a font you can use the `nameToFont` method from the `font` module. From there you can change any attribute of the font you want: family, size, etc. Here's a simple example of a function that sets the size of the default fonts based on the screen size:

```
def initialize_fonts():
    font_size = 12 if root.winfo_screenwidth() <= 1200 else 32
    for font_name in ("TkDefaultFont", "TkTextFont"):
        font = tkFont.nametofont(font_name)
        font.configure(size=font_size)
```

If you call this function before creating any widgets, they will all be created with the new size.

```
root = tk.Tk()
initialize_fonts()
details = CustomerDetails(root, text="Customer Details")
details.pack(side="top", fill="x", expand=False)
```

Comment: means first I have to create the classes for frame and then set their columnconfigure etc commonly? And by doing this the widgets will be shrink and fit in the window?

Comment: I have posted my some code in the question section. Can you please show me how should I make it responsive in my case ?

Comment: @TirthPatel: follow the advice I gave in my answer: configure the weight of the column with the entry widgets, and also use the `sticky` attribute.

Comment: @TirthPatel: that's probably because you haven't modified it to work with your fonts. When I wrote that answer I didn't know what fonts you were using. Don't copy the code, copy the concepts.

Comment: I have use Font which is imported from tkinter.font, how can I make it work ?

Answer (score 0):

I have a suggestion.

instead of building a big and lengthy GUI which does all work in one screen, you can divide it in parts and make the GUI small. (*from 1000x800 to 600x400 i guess monitors cant be smmaler than this*)

Like:

1. Take customer details first in small GUI.
2. then Vehicle details and so on

or:

[Use HTML, CSS, JS to create a responsive GUI(as its much easier to make responsive GUI using HTML, CSS and JS than in tkinter](https://dev.to/kodark/creating-a-modern-gui-for-your-python-application-2mlp)